# Looking for a keyboard with navigation keys (for navigating up/down/left/right multiple-line tex area widgets)

Tags: android, plain-text, virtual-keyboard, keyboard-layout, keyboard

I'm using the default Samsung Keyboard on a Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo Android smartphone.

When composing a Facebook (or other) message, the text often spans multiple lines. Whenever there are more than 5 or so lines, perhaps 7, I can long click the text cursors (the two cursors delimiting the highlighted area) show up and I can then drag up / down / left / right to positioning them where I want. At least this must have been the intention of the team who implemented the Android text area widget.

However, this method makes it impossible to scroll, say, from the last (e.g. 10th) line, to the middle (e.g. 5th line), without the cursor *speedily* moving up to the first line, and vice versa. As a result, I cannot navigate text which spans multiple lines as I would like.

So, anyone know of a keyboard implementing the `↑`, `↓`, `←`, `→` arrow keys?

Answer (score 3):

Definitely a case for **[Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard):**

[image: Hacker's Keyboard] [image: Hacker's Keyboard] [image: Hacker's Keyboard]
<sup>*Hacker's Keyboard* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard); click images for larger variants)</sup>

I'm using this on my tablets, and it's pretty convenient. Highly configurable as well. And especially useful with terminal apps (e.g. administrating a server via SSH), as it also offers all the special keys. Not to forget it also supports a bunch of languages.

So let's see how it meets your requirements. Your major wish where cursor keys: find them in the lower right corner of each screenshot. What else? Navigating multiple rows at once? Check next to the cursor keys, and you also find <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDn</kbd> keys to jump entire screens at once.

Would go to far to describe the app completely. But it's free (and even open-source), so just check it out for yourself! If you prefer: *Hacker's Keyboard* is also [available at F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But now I wonder, is it possible to switch keyboards (I've got Samsung Keyboard and Hacker's Keyboard both checked because I prefer to use the Samsung Keyboard unless I absolutely need the Hacker's Keyboard for the simple reason that less keys means larger keys, which makes it easier to use on medium-sized or small screens). So, how can I switch between these two without having to modify the OS Settings every time?

Comment: Easily. As soon as the keyboard is invoked (i.e. you enter a text area), your statusbar will show a keyboard symbol. Tapping that lets you chose the input method (in this case, it lets you switch between the two keyboards). Which one to be used by default you can define in your "OS Settings" :) And if you're looking for additional alternatives: be welcome to check [my keyboard listings](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_keyboards) :)